# How to move scalebar to the center when working with mapsforge on android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mapsforge

[How?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lq0dy.png)
They use the mapsforge mapping engine in their android application. There was a need to move the scalebar from the bottom corner to the center of the screen,

I read the documentation and couldn't find anything. Can you help me, please?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.